# Google Sheets API V4 not working in IIS Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, iis-7, google-sheets-api

I am using Sheets API V4 to fetch and delete rows from a spreadsheet. Its working fine on localhost but after publishing to IIS server it gives error:

> System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

Below is my code:

```
 UserCredential credential;
 using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret_SheetsAPI.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
 {                    
      string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
      credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets-API-dotnet.json");
      credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
      GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
      Scopes,
      "user",
      CancellationToken.None,
      new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
   }
   var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
   {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential,
        ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
   });
```

I am not able to find any examples for ASP.net Webforms application. Please Help. Thanks

Comment: does it ask you to enter your google username and password when starting it?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks. no it doesn't the verification page doesn't open

Comment: have you got the .credentials/sheets-API-dotnet.json file in your new project?

Comment: Yes I have that file in project and also in inetsrv folder

Comment: I would start by confirming if it can see it,

Comment: also, are you about to check the hierarchy error, it might have more information.

Comment: Yes it can as I was getting not found error previously. ok will check. thanks

Comment: I suggest you could install a fiddler on your server to check what has happened.  It seems that there are something wrong with your IIS application send the request to the google server. Detials about how to use fiddler, you could refer to this [article](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/InstallFiddler).  Besides, I suggest you could also check your server  firewall or proxy setting  to make sure your server could access the google API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. actually I found that this code doesn't work on server it meant to be work on single m/c. Your idea is good would definitely read it.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone having same problem...

I managed to make it work with just one change. Instead of using `OAuth Client ID` from google credentials use `Service Account Key` and the code will run on server as well. There are some changes in code as well, because use can not use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker` as it is only for installed or web apps.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret_SheetsAPI.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                string credPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(
                    System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, ".credentials/sheets-API-dotnet.json");                  
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile("client_secret_SheetsAPI.json").CreateScoped(Scopes);
            }
            var service = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
            });
            String spreadsheetId = "ssID";
```